# Oracle Cloud port forwarding traffic to private VNC subnet

Tags: oracle, vnc, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, bastion-host

as shown in the picture below i want to open a vnc session with VNC-Viewer Client in Windows OS:

[image]

When i want to open a session in VNC-Viewer i get this Error:
[image]

My attemps to reach the private subnet:

1. Check jump: jump to ODI-Private from Bastion: ssh -J opc@xx.xx.xx.xx opc@10.0.19.177
   i can jump successfull
2. Check if VCN is running: ps -ef |grep vnc
   seems like running

[image]

3. Add ingress and exgress Rules for Port 5901 in public and private subnet

[image]

[image]

4. Opening Port: 5901 in Bastion:
   sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=5901/tcp
5. Verify the listening port in Bastion:
   [image]
6. Verify the listening port in ODI Private Subnet:
   [image]
7. Telnet in Bastion to ODI
   [image]

[image]

8. Ping ODI Host

[image]

9. Stopped Firewall in Bastion no success either

I am currently very perplexed and need help.

My Oracle instruction: https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.4/dimgs/getting-started-oracle-cloud-marketplace.html#GUID-CFB26CEA-DE22-4FD4-91DF-D9CAA48847BE

Comment: something to look at, the odi firewall seems to block all traffic by default, details here https://www.ateam-oracle.com/post/setting-up-odi-marketplace-agents-in-high-availability-with-atp and here https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/data-integrator/12.2.1.4/odi-marketplace/configuring-high-availability-odi-oracle-cloud-marketplace.html#GUID-C0759DE6-AB15-4FBB-880D-5A359D4A51F4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your Support. Port 5901 was not enabled permanently.